# Google Apps Script Sheets PasteDataRequest paste to column instead of row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My current script pastes the values just fine but it pastes them across the row from the data coordinate and I need it to paste down the column.  How do I do that?

Example data:
Car, cat, bat, rat

How it’s outputting:

```
| Car | cat | bat | rat |
```

How it needs to be output:

```
Car |
___ 
cat |
___
bat |
___
rat |
```

Example code snippet:

```js
var gridCoordinate = Sheets.newGridCoordinate()
gridCoordinate.sheetID = sheet.getSheetID()
gridCoordinate.rowIndex = "1"
gridCoordinate.columnIndex = "1"

let pasteRequest = Sheets.newPasteDataRequest()
pasteRequest.data = inputValues
pasteRequest.type = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES
pasteRequest.coordinate = gridCoordinate 
pasteRequest.delimiter = ","

let requests = [Sheets.newRequest()]
requests[0].pasteData = pasteRequest;

let batchUpdateRequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
batchUpdateRequest.requests = requests

var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, "REDACTED")
Logger.log(result)
```

Edit to add: inputValues has to be a comma delimited string per the documentation on PasteDataRequests

Comment: I should mention the data isn’t being copied from elsewhere in the sheet, it’s being created in the script which is why I used a pasteDataRequest and not a copyPasteRequest

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. What is `sheet` of `sheet.getSheetID()`? 2. Your sample CSV data is only one row like `Car, cat, bat, rat`? If you have multiple rows, can you provide your expected situation?

Comment: 1: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

Comment: 2: no? Its just the 1 string that needs to be output as a column in the sheet instead of as a row.  The paste function outputs as a row and I can’t figure out how to have it be a column. That’s all

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I understood your 1st answer. But, I cannot understand your 2nd answer. If your CSV data has more than 2 rows, can you provide more sample values? For example, when your sample value is `Car, cat, bat, rat\nCar, cat, bat, rat`, can you provide your expected result?

Comment: There is not more than 2 rows. I gave the expected output in my original question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, by guessing your situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `There is not more than 2 rows. I gave the expected output in my original question.`, it supposes that when your sample value is `Car, cat, bat, rat`, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- When I asked `What is sheet of sheet.getSheetID()?`, you said `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")`. In this case, `sheet.getSheetID()` occurs an error because `getSheetID` should be `getSheetId`. And also, an error occurs at `gridCoordinate.sheetID`. Becuase, in this case, `gridCoordinate.sheetID` is required to be `gridCoordinate.sheetId`.
- In order to put `Car, cat, bat, rat` to a column using your script, `replace(/,/g, "\n")` is used.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
var inputValues = "Car, cat, bat, rat"; // This sample value is from your question.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // This is from your reply.

var gridCoordinate = Sheets.newGridCoordinate();
gridCoordinate.sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); // Modified
gridCoordinate.rowIndex = "1";
gridCoordinate.columnIndex = "1";

let pasteRequest = Sheets.newPasteDataRequest();
pasteRequest.data = inputValues.replace(/,/g, "\n"); // Modified
pasteRequest.type = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
pasteRequest.coordinate = gridCoordinate;
pasteRequest.delimiter = ",";

let requests = [Sheets.newRequest()];
requests[0].pasteData = pasteRequest;

let batchUpdateRequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
batchUpdateRequest.requests = requests;
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, "REDACTED");
Logger.log(result)
```

- When this script is run, the values of `Car, cat, bat, rat` are put to the cells "B2:B5" of the active sheet.

#### Note:

- In your situation, when you want to use Sheets API, I thought that you also might be able to use the following sample.

  ```
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: Utilities.parseCsv(inputValues), majorDimension: "COLUMNS" }, "REDACTED", "Sheet1!B2", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  ```

#### Reference:

- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: Sorry about the typos. They came about during the copying from my computer screen to my phone screen when I typed the question.

Comment: Anyways, this worked.  Switching from a , delimited string to a new line delimited string (with commas still as the set delimiter for the request) made it go from a row to a column.  Thanks!

Comment: @TIsConfused Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how the array is created but assuming its a 1D array ["Car", "cat", "bat", "rat"] it needs to be transformed into a 2D array using testArray() [["Car"], ["cat"], ["bat"], ["rat"]].

If its a string like a csv try testString() where each row is seperated by a new line `\n` and each cell by a comma.

**Code.gs**

```
function testArray() {
  try {
    let a = ["Car", "cat", "bat", "rat"];
    let b = a.map( c => [c] );
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function testString() {
  try {
    let a = "Car\ncat\nbat\nrat";
    let b = Utilities.parseCsv(a);
    console.log(b);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:21:32 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:21:32 AM  Info    [ 'Car', 'cat', 'bat', 'rat' ]
9:21:32 AM  Info    [ [ 'Car' ], [ 'cat' ], [ 'bat' ], [ 'rat' ] ]
9:21:32 AM  Notice  Execution completed

3:12:37 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:12:38 PM  Info    [ [ 'Car' ], [ 'cat' ], [ 'bat' ], [ 'rat' ] ]
3:12:38 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Oh its not an array.  Its a comma delimited string.  PasteDataRequest.data is only a string, not an array.  Thats why I was having trouble

Comment: You must be using some other library because I can't find newPasteDataRequest() in the Google Sheets API documentation.

Comment: Just the regular sheets advanced API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request

Comment: I've added an option where a csv string is passed to the API.  Note your use of `newGridCoordinate`, `newPasteDataRequest`, `newRequest` and `newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` are not a part of the Sheets API documentation.  Are you sure you haven't used another helper library?

Comment: Yes they are. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate

Comment: Just to be clear what your are referencing is the Sheet API.  The methods I mentioned above are not a part of that but from some one elses helper functions.

Comment: Where are you getting that Sheets.newGridCoordinate(), Sheets.newPasteDataRequest(), Sheets.newRequest(), and Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest() are someone else’s helper functions when they are 1: prefaced by the keyword object Sheets, and 2: directly mentioned and used in the documentation I linked?

Comment: Also I haven’t added any other libraries besides the Sheets Advanced API that I linked the documentation of so there isn’t anywhere where they could come from.

Comment: Can you provide a direct link to 'newPasteDataRequest' because I'm not seeing it.  Typically I build an object as required by https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate

Comment: The first link I gave you. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request
Their documentation expects you to know how to translate their JSON examples to their corresponding Apps Scripts functions. If you look at the example from the second link I gave you, it uses multiple of the functions you are saying are a 3rd party helper function.

Comment: You normally build yours the JSON method it seems. Its really similar, the only real difference is that the names are slightly different.  Remove the part that says Sheets.new from the functions I gave and you’ll get the names you’re used to seeing

Comment: Did "\n" work for you.  If so mark this as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I already marked the answer about using a new line as the answer and commented that it worked